# When to use Web Api in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

(First i just want to say i'm sorry if its not worded the best but i have been researching for hours and i thought maybe someone on here could clear this up for me)
Im new to creating web apis and i have been googling just doing some research and i have built a few MVC applications just to get exposed but i never really thought of making an API for it until today. One of the reasons its listed to be useful is it allows your application to be used across tablets and smart phones etc. What im not understanding is how you would do this as in would you just add something to the API so it makes it compatible for all browsers or if i need to re build it using Web API instead of MVC.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your looking at a Web API from the wrong perspective. It's not really about compatibility necessarily, but rather about the ability to reuse the code/back-end functionality.

So rather than having your dependencies all wrapped up in one MVC project, the references are external. This allows for essentially the same functionality across multiple projects as long as the request are being handled in the same manner.

Comment: Alright i think i understand just correct me if im wrong so say im making a Shopping Cart application in MVC i necessarily wouldn't need to build an API for that because the functionality wont need to go across multiple projects.

Comment: But the API is very useful if im making a shopping cart that needs to be mobile as well and not just web because instead of re-coding the shopping cart i could just connect it to the API?

Comment: Yeah, I would say what you are saying is correct. Pretty much it really comes down to the scale of your project and your direction with it. In a business environment It would be commonly a requirement that you separate dependencies with a Web API, but for your project maybe not.

Comment: So i would separate my dependencies into a Web Api and then just use dependency injection?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like an appropriate solution. Of course that is if you are willing to invest that extra time to do so.

Comment: Id give you a thumbs up but  it doesnt show because i guess im not that important lol.

Comment: No problem, I'm no expert but I like to help out where I can. Also, yeah I know how people can be on here sometimes...